# How to Memoize (Deep Compare) Redux Objects Using Reselect with createSelectorCreator()?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, memoization, reselect

### The Situation

Using react redux, in `mapStateToProps` for one of my container components, I pass down an object with 8+ keys for the sake of convenience. (I am aware that passing objects down is an anti-pattern, but the convenience of passing a singular object rather than many individual props is significant in my case.)

## The Question

**Can you use `reselect` to memoize an entire object to pass down through `mapStateToProps`, only passing it down by deep comparing that entire object? If so, what is the proper way to do so?**

### My Attempt

I have read the `reselect` docs section, "Customize equalityCheck for defaultMemoize," and have read through a number of posts where an attempt at memoizing *arrays* using `reselect` are made. Based on this knowledge, I have attempted to do the following, but to no success:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import { createSelector, createSelectorCreator, defaultMemoize } from 'reselect'

const createDeepEqualSelector = createSelectorCreator(
  defaultMemoize,
  _.isEqual,
);

const getLargeObject = createDeepEqualSelector(
  (state) => {
    // Get the individual values from state
    const {
      val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8, val9, val10
    } = state;

    // Create a convenient object that contains all of those values to pass down to props
    const constructedObject = {
      val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8, val9, val10
    };

    return constructedObject;
  },
  constructedObject => constructedObject,
);

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const objProp = getLargeObject(state);

  return {
    objProp,
    // ... other props
  };
}
```

### The (Unfortunate) Alternative

If I do not do things way, I end up with 8+ individual selectors, with a large `createSelector` call. This seems more redundant than necessary, and makes me wonder if there is a better way to do this. As a demonstration:

```
const getVal1 = (state) => state.val1;
const getVal2 = (state) => state.val2;
...

const getLargeObject = createSelector(
  [
    getVal1,
    getVal2,
    ...
  ],
  (
    val1,
    val2,
    ...
  ) => {
    const largeObject = {
      val1,
      val2,
      ...
    };

    return largeObject;
  },
);
```

Thank you for your any help you can give!